# rest api for the sharepoint - import data

Tags: sharepoint-online, sharepoint-server

I need rest api endpoint to import and export data to the SharePoint list.
I know I can do this without code but in my solution, I'm using rest API.

how can I achieve this?

Answer (score 1):

This is a good place to start:

https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/dev/sp-add-ins/complete-basic-operations-using-sharepoint-rest-endpoints

Answer (score 1):

For crud operation to SharePoint list data with rest api, here is a quite detailed tutorial which you can have a look at:

https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/990131/CRUD-Operation-to-List-Using-SharePoint-Rest-API

https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/dev/sp-add-ins/working-with-lists-and-list-items-with-rest